# How can I fill the empty gap between two parts of my photoshop document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a website page in photoshop. In the middle I deleted an element and I want the empty space between the top and bottom of the document to be closed. So the top and bottom part merge into one document again. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic Photoshop operation and there are several tools and methods you could use in this situation... Have you tried anything at all?? I'm voting to close this question as tech support. It shows no effort or research at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make a fill layer which is white and then add it to the background

If you need to you can merge the layers to flatten the artwork

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a New layer below the layer of the image.

Keep the Foreground color as white. Then select the new layer and press Alt+Delete.

This will fill the up the space with white color.

[image]